# How to quickly enter boot menu?

Tags: motherboard, uefi

I use an Asus Z170 motherboard. Is there a quick way (one key) to get to the boot menu? Right now I use 'Del to enter BIOS setup' (slow) then 'F8 boot menu'.

Comment: Try tapping F8 or ESC.

Answer (score 1):

Just press F8, instead of del, and you'll directly enter boot menu